# Images not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, image

I have a set of small images which is working fine in Firefox but not in Google Chrome. The html code is this:

```
<li class="links">
<a href="tassa-di-soggiorno"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/taxNero.jpg"></a>
<a href="eco-friendly-hotel"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eco.jpg"></a>
<a href="pet-friendly-hotel"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pet.jpg"></a>
<a href="3130"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/diverability.jpg"></a>
</li>
```

And the css styles:

```
#nav-bar li.links a {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 1px;
width: 40px;
}
```

Here's the link to the webpage to see it: http://www.alcappellorosso.it

You should see the images right below the left navigation menu.

Comment: to me, images appear fine in both FF and Chrome

Comment: You should submit screenshots of what the actual and expected appearance is, as I don't see any missing images (but I don't know what it should look like, either).

Comment: Folks, the is realy such error in CHROME.

Comment: @DaneSoul Then why doesn't my CHROME have such an error? Although I should note that there is actually an error in the HTML output, too.

Comment: I don't know, may be version issues. Mine chrome is portable and possibly not the recent version.

Comment: Did you open the developer panel (F12) and looked up the resource tab what chrome tells you about the http response of the image requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your CSS:

```
#nav-bar li {
 height: 35px;
}
```

Or value more situable for your design.

Comment: Could be a timing problem - Chrome renders the elements with a height of 0px before the images are loaded.